# EJS syntax error : unexpected token ; while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a syntax error when I trie to render this part of my template with EJS (on a node server).

The error is in this code part, I'm sure I have a pb with tags "<%" but I don't understand where.

```
<p>
  <% tasks.map(task => ( %>
    <%= task %>
  <% )) %> 
</p>
```

Here is my full template :

```
<h1>My todolist</h1>

<p><% tasks.map(task => ( %>
    <%= task %>
   <% )) %> 
</p>

<form method="post" action="/task">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add task" name="newTask" />
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What is this `<%= task %>`.

Comment: it's supposed to be my task item render, so it's supposed to be javascript

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer. I finally solved the problem. "task" wasn't the trouble.

It seems I can't use ES6 syntax to quickly return something

I changed this :

```
<p><% tasks.map(task => ( %>
    <%= task %>
   <% )) %> 
</p> %>
```

with this :

```
<p><% tasks.map(task => { %>
    <%= task %>
   <% }) %> 
</p>
```

And now it works perfectly !

Comment: I just ask about it because it is shown that the task is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <h1>My todolist</h1>

    <p>
    <% tasks.map(task => {
    %> <%=task %><%});%>
    </p>



    <form method="post" action="/task">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add task" name="newTask" />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
```